# Sliding CSS Javascript bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to have the blue bar under the list items shrink to the size of the list item clicked and position itself directly underneath it? Additionally, if the opposite list item is clicked, the bar would slide underneath it. Is this possible with just pure CSS or Vanilla JavaScript? Anything helps, cheers.

```css
.buttons {
list-style-type: none;
    margin:0px auto 0;
    padding:0;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.buttons li {
  float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-right:1px solid white;
    line-height:45px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-weight:bolder;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    color:#005bab;
    background-color:#e2ecf6;
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:50%;
}

.buttons li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
       
.buttons li:hover{
  color: #005bab;
  background-color: #d2e2ef;
}
.bottombar1{
       content: "";
       display:block;
       height:0.5em;
       width:100%;
       background-color:#00688B;
}
#panelCanada,#panelInternational {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
   <ul class="buttons">
      <li class="flip"> Canada</li>
      <li class="flip">International</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<br style="line-height:49px;"/>
<div class="bottombar1"></div>
```

Comment: `<br style="line-height:49px;"/>` thought about using some top margin to your bottombar? or properly clear floats?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yup, didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning and alter the position and width of the bar based on the `offsetLeft` and `offsetWidth` of the `li` you clicked on.

```js
var flip = document.getElementsByClassName("flip"),
  bb = document.getElementById("bottombar1");

function clickHandler(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var left = this.offsetLeft, width = this.offsetWidth;
    bb.style.left = left + "px";
    bb.style.width = width + "px";
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < flip.length; i++) {
  clickHandler(flip[i]);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2em;
}
.topnav {
  position: relative;
}
.buttons {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px auto 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.buttons li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  line-height: 45px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bolder;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #005bab;
  background-color: #e2ecf6;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
}

.buttons li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.buttons li:hover {
  color: #005bab;
  background-color: #d2e2ef;
}

.bottombar1 {
  height: 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00688B;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 5px);
  transition: left .5s, width .5s;
  left: 0;
}
.topnav {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
   <ul class="buttons">
      <li class="flip"> Canada</li>
      <li class="flip">International</li>
   </ul>
  <div class="bottombar1" id="bottombar1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's perfect, but is it possible with Vanilla JavaScript

Comment: @DisplayName  oops! Sorry, missed that part. Just a sec, I'll rewrite it.

Comment: @MichaelCoker really well done! Up'd. P.S: I'd just move functions away from loops - use just function calls, not definitions.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks! I really appreciate the feedback, too! pardon me, I'm not as good with JS as I'd like and focus more on CSS/layout... but I'm really looking to learn. What's a "definition" exactly?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan do you mean something like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRbLrK I'm also curious what the advantage is, or if it's just a personal preference?

Comment: @MichaelCoker exactly that! just, now you should use `el.addEventListener` instead of `flip[i].addEventListener` ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan nice! Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

The more flexible way would be using JS, but yeah,
**CSS, why not...**

Use hidden `<input type="radio" id="" name="">` and than use CSS's nearest sibling `~` to target any desired next-near sibling element selector.

The elements to trigger the `:checked` state change are the `<label for="">` elements that need to be placed inside the LI elements:

```css
/*QuickReset*/ *{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;} html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}


ul.buttons {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.buttons li {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  color: #005bab;
  background-color: #e2ecf6;
}
ul.buttons li label{
  display: block;
  padding: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.buttons li:hover {
  color: #005bab;
  background-color: #d2e2ef;
}
.bottombar{
  position: relative;
  height: 0.5em;
  background: #00688B;
  width:100%;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

/* don't show radio buttons switchers
and content */
input[id^=switch],
[id^=switchContent]{
  display:none;
}

/* when :checked, target the nearest sibling bottombar */
#switch1:checked ~ .bottombar{
  width: 50%;
  left:0;
  /*transform: translateX( 0% );*/
}
#switch2:checked ~ .bottombar{
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /*transform: translateX( 100% );*/
}

/* Show content */
#switch1:checked ~ #switchContent1{
  display: block;
}
#switch2:checked ~ #switchContent2{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <ul class="buttons">
    <li><label for="switch1">Canada</label></li>
    <li><label for="switch2">International</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<input id="switch1" type="radio" name="sw_1">
<input id="switch2" type="radio" name="sw_1">

<div class="bottombar"></div>

<div id="switchContent1"><h1>CANADAAA</h1></div>
<div id="switchContent2"><h1>INTERNATIONALLL</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Luddens Desirs answer in Vanilla Javascript. It requires a bit more manual labor, so for the slight performance boost using CCS3 animations for such a simple effect, it would be better to go with the other javascript animation answers.

```js
// store relevent elements
var can = document.getElementById('can');
var int = document.getElementById('int');
var botBar1 = document.getElementsByClassName('bottombar1')[0];

can.addEventListener("click", function() { 
 // replace classes with first class name
 botBar1.className = botBar1.className.split(" ")[0];
 // add class
 botBar1.className += ' toCanada';
});

int.addEventListener("click", function() { 
 // replace classes with first class name
 botBar1.className = botBar1.className.split(" ")[0];
 // add class
 botBar1.className += ' toInternational';
});
```

```css
.buttons {
list-style-type: none;
    margin:0px auto 0;
    padding:0;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.buttons li {
  float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-right:1px solid white;
    line-height:45px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-weight:bolder;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    color:#005bab;
    background-color:#e2ecf6;
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:50%;
}

.buttons li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
       
.buttons li:hover{
  color: #005bab;
  background-color: #d2e2ef;
}
.bottombar1{
       content: "";
       display:block;
       height:0.5em;
       width:100%;
       background-color:#00688B;
       
      -webkit-transition: all 1s; // Chrome
      -moz-transition: all 1s; // Mozilla
      -o-transition: all 1s; // Opera
      transition: all 1s; 
} 
 
.toInternational{
   transform: translate(25%, 0px) scaleX(.5);  
}
.toCanada{
   transform: translate(-25%, 0px) scaleX(.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.1.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="topnav">
   <ul class="buttons">
      <li id = "can" class="flip"> Canada</li>
      <li id = "int" class="flip">International</li>
   </ul>
</div> 
<br style="line-height:49px;"/>
<div class="bottombar1"></div>
```